# Reusing function with the same logic diff args

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, kubernetes

Is there a way to optimize the following code? I mean instead of those two functions, create only one that support both, as the logic inside is identical, only the parameter of `v1.EphemeralContainer`
And `v1.Container` is different, any idea if I can optimize this code?

I want to reduce the duplication however the types is different, maybe with generics? is it possible to use only one function?

Container
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/3bf57e3ded6d69d4a7c03de272bb1f0f1c3ea8e4/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L2209

https://go.dev/play/p/_lWiBhhgVjg

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func main() {
    // List all the pods in the cluster
    pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, pod := range pods.Items {
        for _, container := range pod.Spec.Containers {
            if container.SecurityContext != nil {
                val1(container, pod)
            }
        }
        for _, container := range pod.Spec.InitContainers {
            if container.SecurityContext != nil {
                fnc1(container, pod)
            }
        }
        for _, container := range pod.Spec.EphemeralContainers {
            if container.SecurityContext != nil {
                fnc2(container, pod)
            }
        }
    }
}

func fnc2(container v1.EphemeralContainer, pod v1.Pod) {
    if container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation != nil && !*container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has escalatable ephemeralContainer %s\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
    if container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot != nil && *container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot == false {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has ephemeralContainer %s running as root\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
}

func fnc1(container v1.Container, pod v1.Pod) {
    if container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation != nil && !*container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has escalatable container %s\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
    if container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot != nil && *container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot == false {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has container %s running as root\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using `generics`.
NOTE:
This is achievable only with go > 1.18

Example:

```golang
func fnc2[T v1.EphemeralContainer | v1.Container](container T, pod v1.Pod) {
    if container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation != nil && !*container.SecurityContext.AllowPrivilegeEscalation {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has escalatable ephemeralContainer %s\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
    if container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot != nil && *container.SecurityContext.RunAsNonRoot == false {
        fmt.Printf("Pod %s has ephemeralContainer %s running as root\n", pod.Name, container.Name)
    }
}
```

Then you have to call the method by this way:

```golang
fnc2[YOUR_TYPE](container,pod)
```